# Sharks with frickin’ laser beams attached to their heads

Tags: building, piece-information, the-lego-movie

The Lego Movie does not only feature sharks and lasers but also laser sharks:

[image: Still from the Lego Movie showing a shark with a *frickin’* laser beam attached to its head]

However, a [Lego shark](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2547c01) only has one place where other pieces can be attached and that’s located on its belly.
Hence, I am asking: **How can I attach a laser beam (or anything else for that matter) to my shark’s head?**

In the above still, the shark’s jaw seems to be detached, but that does not seem very healthy and still it only provides little space to attach anything.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: I am pretty sure. I extracted it from the movie myself. It’s in the scene where Metalbeard describes how they tried and failed to enter Lord Business’s tower. ([Here it is on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-MdmLOEC-8).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The LEGO Agents [Speedboat Rescue (8633)](https://brickset.com/sets/8633-1/Speedboat-Rescue) set has a set with laser sharks. The set uses a new version of the LEGO shark with two studs on the top behind the head.

[image]

Sadly the shark only appeared in two sets, this one and [Brickbeard's Bounty (6243)](https://brickset.com/sets/6243-1/Brickbeard-s-Bounty) and because of their limited release they are very expensive on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=79786&idColor=86&view=buy&ccName=4530672#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:86,%22ss%22:%22UK%22,%22cond%22:%22N%22%7D).

For the original shark you could use a small Technic rubber band (or any small rubber band) to attach a laser.

In the example below, The body of each laser uses a Technic [pin joiner](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62462#T=C), the rubber band runs along the slot in the brick so it's kept in place. The back end of the laser is joined together with [a flexible rubber axle connector](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=45590#T=C).

[image]